# Area covered in a specific time interval

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

We know from Kepler's 2nd law that area swept by a planet in equal interval of times are equal, but is there a specific equation that can allow us to calculate area swept $A$  by a planet in a given interval of time $t$ to $t'$?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for can be found form the [areal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_velocity),
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$
which we can re-write as,
$$
A=\int\,{\rm d}A=\frac12\int r^2\dot{\theta}\,{\rm d}t
$$
Since the [angular momentum is conserved](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/amom.html#amp), then $r^2\dot\theta=\ell$ and we would end up with,
$$
A=\frac12\ell \int_t^{t'}\,{\rm d}t=\frac12\ell\left(t'-t\right)
$$

Comment: well, I dont think this much helps the OP :) Google will tell you a lot about a planet, say Earth - but not $\ell$

Comment: @Ilja: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205526/

Comment: No, I don't see how this helps either; and I can think of the answer myself, so I don't think the OP will get it from there. I mean, how to compute this from measurable (or googleable) quantities. First I thought, you had just to add some small pieces, but on second thought I have added a second answer, because the pieces are enough by themselves. You derivation is nice for a physicist, but for normal mortals I think my approach is what they search for; I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you accept, that the 2nd law holds (which @Kyle Kanos has derived from angular momentum conservation), then you need no calculations at all.

The area is proportional to the time, so in one year (which is different for other planets than Earth :)) you sweep the whole circle: $\pi R^2$. This assumes a circular orbit, of course, but I guess the "average distance to the sun" you find in tables about the planets is calculated just so, that this formula holds. At least in good approximation^^

Thus the area has to be $A = \frac{t'-t}{T}\pi R^2$