# Total angular momentum of a planet orbiting a star

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, celestial-mechanics

Would the total angular momentum of a planet orbiting a star while rotating on it's axis be the sum of the orbital rotational momentum and the rotational momentum about it's axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total angular momentum of earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205526/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the rotation about the axis is negligible compared to the orbital angular momentum. For an electron orbiting a nucleus the two kinds of angular momentum are the same order of magnitude

Answer (score 0):

For large bodies the rotational angular momentum can be neglected but not in case of small bodies.  However the answer to your question is definitely yes.